# Outlook addin doesn't show when composer window is launched from from any external application

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Like when I promptly open outlook, and click on "New E-Mail", I see my addin loads on New Email window (That's where the addin is supposed to be).
But when I open a doc in Word/Excel and click File>>Click and Save>>Send Using EMail>>Send as Attachment. Now it does open outlook "New Email window", but my addin doesn't load in the sidebar.
Similarly, when opening Outlook following any link like "mailto:this@email.com"

Any suggestion/pointer as to how to achieve this behaviour?

Edit:
I tried a timer, with an interval of around 14 seconds (just for testing).
The timer event does execute but I don't get an inspector which should be MailItem. Here's the code:

```
 private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            diagnosticLog.Debug("In OnTimed Event!");
            InspectorWrapper wrapper;
            foreach (Outlook.Inspector item in Application.Inspectors)
            {
                diagnosticLog.Debug("In OutlookInspector Loop: " + item.ToString());
                if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    diagnosticLog.Debug("Inspector is a MialItem: " + item.ToString());
                    diagnosticLog.Debug("In OnTimed Event!");
                    if (!inspectorWrappersValue.TryGetValue(item, out wrapper))
                    {
                        inspectorWrappersValue.Add(item, new InspectorWrapper(item));
                        diagnosticLog.Debug("new Inspector Added");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This line:

```
 foreach (Outlook.Inspector item in Application.Inspectors)
```

does get one inspector but it's never an Outlook.MailItem, hence I can't access the inspector where I should add my addin.

inspectorWrappersValue is a dictionary and it's in the constructor of InspectorWrapper that I initialize my Addin UI.

```
 inspectorWrappersValue.Add(item, new InspectorWrapper(item));
```

This inspector is being opened by Excel (sending attachment)

Comment: Try the "as" operator instead. What is the value of the item.Class property (all OOM objects expose the Class property)?

Answer (score 1):

How/when do you add your own UI? Keep in mind that Inspectors.NewInspector event does not fire if the inspector is being opened using Simple MAPI or a mailto link.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding the new inspector in Addin_Startup event and add add my custom pane and contained controls to compose window right side.

Comment: So how can I go about doing this, I see a Salesforce/Contact Monkey addin which has their plugin shown when outlook compose window is opened through word or any other app using mailto link.

Comment: You can have a timer that iterates through the Application.Inspectors collection. If there is an inspector that you did not handle yet, you can run your code there and then.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean I have to write a service for this which will run in background and do this?

Comment: Why do you need a service? COM addin would work just fine.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I'm not being able to get the open MailItem Inspecor